# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Razor Pages: Dependency Injection in RazorPage.cshtml.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a Asp.Net Core RazorPages application and am trying to inject the WebHosting environment so I can access files. I have a folder called "Reports" under the solution folder. I'm injecting the IWebHostEnvironment in my RazorPage code behind this way:

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment1;
    public IndexModel(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        this.webHostEnvironment1 = webHostEnvironment;
    }
    public void OnGet() {            
        string reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment1.ContentRootPath, "Reports", "TestReport.repx");
        Console.WriteLine("CONTENTRootPath: " + webHostEnvironment1.ContentRootPath);
        Console.WriteLine("WEBRootPath: " + webHostEnvironment1.WebRootPath);
        Console.WriteLine("ReportPath: " + reportPath);            
    }
```

My Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        WebHostEnvironment = environment;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }
```

When I run my app, it's not throwing any errors, but it's not writing to the console, the contentrootpath and the reportfilepath. Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't change anything in startup.cs. And just paste the code you provided, and it works fine.

[image]

And I can see the console details in `Output`, you can try it.

Step 1. Click Output.

Step 2. Click the dropdown list.

Step 3. Choose Web Server.

[image]